# If statement clarification of AND/OR

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm sorry to ask such an easy question.. I just need some clarifications, because sometimes I mix the differences up.

Can somebody please help me by explaining the difference between the following if statements?

```
sending = true;
if (sending && e.AssetType == AssetType.Notecard) //#1
```

vs.

```
if ((sending) && (e.AssetType == AssetType.Notecard)) //#2
```

vs.

```
if (sending || e.AssetType == AssetType.Notecard) //#3
```

vs.

```
if ((sending) || (e.AssetType == AssetType.Notecard)) //#4
```

In this specific case, I need it to evaluate to something like:
"If(sending == true AND e.AssetType == AssetType.Notecard)"

In an other case I need the if statement to check one string and contents of a list like:
"If(string == "Name" OR List.Contains("string"))

Comment: Are you asking what `||` means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first and the second statements are the same (parenthesis are not obligatory in this case, because of C# evaluation priorities!)

```
if (sending && e.AssetType == AssetType.Notecard)
if ((sending) && (e.AssetType == AssetType.Notecard))
```

just as:

```
if ((sending == true) && e.AssetType == AssetType.Notecard))
if ((sending) && (e.AssetType == AssetType.Notecard))
```

Also the 3° and the 4° statement will give the same result, for the same reason mentioned above: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx

I would use these statements:

```
if (sending && (e.AssetType == AssetType.Notecard))
```

and:

```
if ((string == "Name") || List.Contains("string"))
```

(but please take care of string comparison modes, such as upper/lower cases and cultures:

```
String.Compare(string, "Name", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0
```

compares strings without regard of the case and with the current culture)

Comment: Ahh, you never stop learning. THank you for the string compare..
What I am usually doing is to cast the strings to lowercase strings in the if statements, like: if(string.ToLower() == "comparison string")

Thank you very much for your help. :)

Comment: You're welcome! With .ToLower() also works well, but it doesn't care about culture (don't know if you need it!)...

Answer (score 2):

There is no *any* difference in those codes.

`if ((sending) && (e.AssetType == AssetType.Notecard))` and `if (sending && e.AssetType == AssetType.Notecard)` evaluates into the same thing.

`if(sending == true)` or `if(sending`) is the same thing too.

---

**If** you're asking about difference between `||` and `&&`:

- `||` is a LOGICAL-OR.     It's enough that only **one** condition would be TRUE to pass `if`
- `&&` is a LOGICAL-AND.    **All** conditions must be TRUE in order to pass `if`

In both cases the evaluation will be done from the *left to right*.

Example of sequence:
`if ((sending) && (e.AssetType == AssetType.Notecard))` => if `sending==true` AND `..rest..`

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than this.  The OP has clarified that `sending == true` is a test case, `&& != ||`, and you haven't explained *why* they evaluate to the same thing (order of operations).

Comment: `if(sending == true) or if(sending)` -- Irrelevant.

Comment: I do know that if(sending) and if(sending == true) is the same.
I also know that || is Logical OR and that && is Logical AND..

What I needed was how to make sure I have one IF statement that gives "Is sending == true AND rest..."
And another giving "if sending == true OR rest..."

Comment: And the reason for asking..  I have seen so many different ways to make them (setting each condition in separate parenthesis, or do the whole statement between the same parenthesis, as well as some examples saying "this is an if OR statement" using &&, and some sayign "This is an if AND statement" using ||).

I have just gotten confused by it all and need some clarification. :)

Comment: @Rickard So you're asking us to tell you how to write every conditional expression you'll ever need to write?  Tall order.

Answer (score 1):

For the first and second statements produce the same result and for the third and fourth statements also produce the same result.

A couple of things to clarify:

- In this case, parentheses are not required and it is just extra code.
- When you use Logical-AND operation, the first part is always evaluated, and the second part will only be evaluated if the first part is true.
- When you use Logical-OR operation, both parts are always evaluated.
- When you have more than +2 expressions, then use parentheses to clarify your intentions. e.g. `if(A && B || C)` is the same as `if((A && B) || C)` because [the Operators Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4(v=vs.140).aspx). but if you want the logical-OR operation to be execute first, then you must use parentheses to override the precedence `if(A && (B || C))`

  - Furthermore, `if(A && B == C)` is the same as `if(A && (B == C))` because  Equality operation has higher precedence than logical-AND